# add one year to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a Microsoft SQL database table with inapp purchases named:

```
UserInAppPurchase
```

for our app with expiration dates in it (and much more) for our inapp purchases.  If the date is in this month we would like to add one year to the current expiration date (pseudocode):

```
If column ProductID = 'com.crew.1year' 
AND column Platform = 'Android' 
AND column ValidTo = in this month

Then
    add one year to the date in ValidTo
```

The date format in `ValidTo` is like this:

```
   2018-05-15 00:00:00.000
```

Up there the date and all ifs are fulfilled, now the date would have to be updated by one year.

I am struggling in creating a sql query for this. I am very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for something more like this (using Tim's initial SQL):

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET ValidTo = DATEADD(year, 1, ValidTo)
WHERE [Platform] = 'Android'
  AND ProductID = 'com.crew.1year'
  AND ValidTo >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,GETDATE()),0)
  AND ValidTo < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,GETDATE())+1,0);
```

This ensures you're only updating rows for this year, but also, maintains SARGability, as there are no functions applied to the column `ValidTo` in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try this update query:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET ValidTo = DATEADD(year, 1, ValidTo)
WHERE
    Platform = 'Android' AND
    ProductID = 'com.crew.1year' AND
    DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(month, ValidTo);
-- and if we also want to restrict to expiries in the same year:
-- AND DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(year, ValidTo);
```

This update query will shift the `ValidTo` dates forward by one year for those records whose `ValidTo` dates are in the same month as the current month.  I also added the checks on the `Platform` and `ProductID`.

Comment: @Andreas if it is the same month but different year? should the update still be done?

Comment: well it is not me for sure

Comment: Although I'm not a fan of a non-SARGable query, not me either. It's certainly not worth the downvote as it does what the OP has asked.

Comment: @Larnu I upvoted your answer, because it's streamlined.  Not sure about the downvotes :-?

Comment: It would annoy me as well. I've seen a larger volume of downvotes with no comment recently. Not sure why, but it is disappointing. If someone doesn't agree with my, or another person's answer, the insight they might have is invaluable to the "answerer", it might well help them improve it; which also enriches the OP's experience too.

Comment: Interesting to know my stats aren't isolated :-)